# Using ItemContainerGenerator make fire event SelectionChanged

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

In a WPF application as soon as I call this

```
SurfaceListBoxItem categoryItem = (SurfaceListBoxItem)CategoriesListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(CategoriesListBox.SelectedItem);
```

an event for `SelectionChange` for

CategoriesListBox

fires.
How to avoid this?
Alternatively could you suggest me another way how to swap the data template